# Switch disabled on input with angular 2

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular

I use bootstrap with angular 2 and try to activate/deactivate a number input with a checkbox.

```
<input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="chk1">
<input type="number" disabled="chk1"  />
```

Does not work. Also setting the class `disabled` does not work with inputs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should wrap disabled attribute with `[]`(property binding)

```
[disabled]="chk1"
```

[**Plunkr Here**](http://plnkr.co/edit/labNfyH6Mmh8RMBN8Xuq?p=preview)